# Ansible replace a value in big config file

Tags: regex, ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I have a config file with more than 3000 lines, where i  need to change/replace only few parameters.
since the config file is huge. am unable to use the template.

Need help in replacing the below parameters.

```
  gateway-config {
    enable = true
    host-name = "car-cache"
    port = 202
    batch-size = 100
    patterns = ["^((test))"]
    type = LINE
    prefix = "stats."${auth}".service"
  }


  k9-config {
    enable = true

    send-enable = false

    host-name = ${auth}

    connection-timeout = 120000

    read-timeout = 60000

    proxy = ""

    project = "Networking"

    period = 120
```

I need to replace the `enable = false` to `enable = true` only on some-config but when i use replace module the whole `enable = false` is replaced in the config file.

Comment: I Used shell module awk comand. but it results with changed even if it didnt make the actual change.
sed -i '/^\\s*hite-config\\s*{\\s*/!b;n;c\\ \\ \\ \\ enable = false' /etc/repli.conf

Comment: Why are you unable to use a template? This would in my opinion be the way to go here.

Comment: @toydarian: I can give you a handful of use cases where it is not always the best solution, including when the config file is huge (as reported by OP) and you don't necessarily have all the references for all the values in your inventory. An other example I can give is changing only some values (e.g. a listening port, a log level..) in a default generated config file at application install where you want to make sure you can catch the new additions/deletions in that file when the application upgrades without having the burden to maintain that template yourself on every new release.

Comment: @Zeitounator I didn't say that there are cases where `replace` is better. But I do like templates a little bit too much, though. I guess the optimal solution depends on how much OP has to change this config and where it comes from

Comment: Yeah template wont work in my case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can actually use the [replace module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/replace_module.html) with the `after` and `before` parameters:

```yaml
- name: Replace between the expressions (requires Ansible >= 2.4)
  replace:
    path: /path/to/your/file
    after: 'gateway-config {'
    before: '}'
    regexp: '^(\s*enable = )false$'
    replace: '\g<1>true'
```

Comment: This could be enhanced by matching any type of indentation just in case there are differences between hosts/versions of the file: `regexp: '^(\\s*enable = )false$'`, `replace: '\\g<1>true'`

Comment: Why the double slashes, when using single quotes, we need a single slash, right?

Comment: Oups ! My bad ! Typed too fast. Yes no need for double backslashes here.

Comment: @Zeitounator I dont see any changes happened in my file. Basically below is the correct content from the config file

  gateway-config {
    enable = true
    host-name = "car-cache"
    port = 201
    batch-size = 100
    patterns = ["^((?!(test).*$"]
    type = LINE
    prefix = "stats."${auth}".service"
  }


  k2-config {
    enable = true

    send-enable = false

    host-name = ${auth}

    connection-timeout = 120000

    read-timeout = 60000

    proxy = ""

Comment: @celcoprab which one do you want to change? `k2-config` or `k9-config` or `gateway-config`?

Comment: @toydarian gateway-config

Comment: The regex in the `after` parameter specifies in which block it should replace the line. I changed it to `gateway-config` in my example, but you can put any regexp.

Comment: I should have thoroughly tested with the entire solution.... The problem is with the before and after regexp which apply to the entire file with DOTALL enabled (see documentation). @toydarian: I have edited the answer with a working solution. As a POC, you can see: https://gist.github.com/zeitounator/184acbbfca8e2b22bfc5b4b680b6b5c9

Comment: "msg": "Pattern for before/after params did not match the given file: ^gateway-config {(?P<subsection>.*?)^}$"

Comment: @celcoprab check the updated code and the last comment from Zeitounator

Answer (score 0):

can you use replace module:

```
---
- name: Replace variable
  replace:
   path: "/etc/repli.conf"
   after: "hite-config {"
   regexp: "enable = false"
   replace: "enable = true"
```

Comment: This will also change `send-enable = false` to `send-enable = true`